# Connection handle ID getting wrong in BLE header Nordic nRF52832

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I am developing one solution using nRF52832 BLE which has one or more BLE peripherals and only one central device. This concept is based on BLE star network everything is working for one BLE peripheral. But now the problem is when I connect two BLE peripherals at the same time to central and start transmitting data. But incoming packets are getting wrong connection ID.

I want to identify which device data coming at central side when more BLE peripherals are connected and transmitting at the same time.

Can anyone please help me understanding the BLE header transmission and receiving process? I know BLE 48 bit unique address also able to read in central, but if more packets are coming from different devices, how do I know which packet is coming from which device?

Comment: Just a quick note; you'll get the best (and probably fastest) responses for anything nRF related on the [NordicSemi Devzone](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com).  Sometimes you'll also get replies from Nordic employees themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,
I have already create question on Nordic dev. zone as well.

Comment: Each connection gets a connection handle. That one is used in every events and function calls to distinguish between the connections.